# Event for ExtJs after Store Load

Tags: extjs

I want to fire an event in ExtJS grid after storeLoad(). Is there any event which I can use other than after render.

```
afterrender: function(grid) {
            var store = grid.getStore();
            if (store.isLoaded()) {
               // not getting debugger here.
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the load event on your store:

```
var store = grid.getStore();
store.on('load', function(){
    //Your function here
});
```

**EDIT :** You should check whether the store is already loaded or not:

```
var handler = function(){ /* Your function here */ }
if (store.isLoaded()) {
    handler.apply(this);
} else {
    store.on('load', handler, this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But where should I do this ? IN init function or in afterrender function

Comment: @David In the *afterrender* function should be fine

Comment: @David Or if your store have *autoload* set to *false*, just before you call the *load()* function

Comment: Thanks a ton Ludovic

Comment: @PredragStojadinović Maybe your store is already loaded ? You should check if this is the case then call your function their if it is already loaded.

Comment: @ludovic-feltz I checked with both isLoading and isLoaded, both were false :( I ended up using a 100ms timeout check for isLoaded to be true, then I did my stuff on the store and that worked...

Comment: @PredragStojadinović I made an edit, this doesn't works for you? That is weird...

Comment: @ludovic-feltz it is, but I found a workaround so... not investing more time into this right now...

Comment: @PredragStojadinović Maybe you should post your workaround here as an answer, it may help futur people who have the same problem :) (I will upvote you so you will have more visibility)

Answer (score 0):

Only posting this on @ludovic-feltz request :)

I consider this a hack and not a *proper* solution...

Basically, after the render I delay the isLoaded check a tiny bit, and if it is not loaded I keep repeating it every 100ms until the store is loaded to set the sorting, or do anything else with it.

I went this way because `store.isLoading()` gave me `false` :(

```
listen: {
    component: {
        'grid': {
            afterrender: 'onGridAfterRender'
        }
    }
},

onGridAfterRender: function () {
    setTimeout(this._setInitialSorting.bind(this), 10);
},

_setInitialSorting: function () {
    var view = this.getView();
    var grid = view.down('grid');
    var store = grid.getStore();

    // remove this console.log's
    console.log('\n_setInitialSorting', new Date().getTime(), store.isLoading(), store.isLoaded());
    
    if (store.isLoaded()) {
        store.sort([{property: 'column1', direction: 'ASC'}]);
        return;
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        this._setInitialSorting();
    }.bind(this), 100);
},
```

I just added the console.log's above to see what happened, and this is the result:

```
_setInitialSorting 1593589691157 false false
_setInitialSorting 1593589691258 true false
_setInitialSorting 1593589691360 true false
_setInitialSorting 1593589691584 false true
```

I wish I did this before, though :D

So it *seems* that `isLoading` is initially `false` in the `afterrender` event! But 100ms later it goes to `true`!

So, I changed the timeout to only 10ms, to get some spam:

```
_setInitialSorting 1593589864967 false false
_setInitialSorting 1593589865007 true false
_setInitialSorting 1593589865016 true false
...
_setInitialSorting 1593589865159 true false
_setInitialSorting 1593589865165 true false
_setInitialSorting 1593589865383 false true
```

Again, the first `isLoading` check after the `afterrender` event is `false` and then becomes `true`...

BTW, for full disclosure, I **did** try:

```
listen: {
    store: {
        '*': {
            load: 'onStoreLoaded',
        }
    }
},
```

But it just made the UI keep blinking and not showing any data :(